# Why maven is not showing correct OS version in Mac Big Sur

Tags: java, macos, maven

I upgraded Mac OS from Catalina to Big Sur but "$mvn --version"
shows the os version as 10.16 as:

```
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.2/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_192, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.16", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

whereas when i run the shell command:

```
$sw_vers
```

i got output as:

```
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.5.2
BuildVersion:   20G95
```

So why `mvn --version` does not show OS version as 11.5.2?

Comment: Maven uses `System.getProperty("os.version")` code to get system's version. This code depends on native code, which is build backward compatible. As [this article](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/08/13/macos-version-numbering-isnt-so-simple/) says if application is build with 10.15 SDK, application will report Big Sur as 10.16, if application  is build with 11.0 SDK, it will report version 11. You can try to reinstall java and check again. But 10.16 is correct version for Big Sur

Comment: @geobreeze Why not make an Answer of your Comment?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [geobreeze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4655217/geobreze):

Maven uses `System.getProperty("os.version")` code to get system's version. This code depends on native code, which is build backward compatible.

As [this article](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/08/13/macos-version-numbering-isnt-so-simple/) says, if an application is built with 10.15 SDK, it will report Big Sur as 10.16. If an application is built with 11.0 SDK, it will report version 11.

You can try to reinstall java and check again. But 10.16 is a correct version for Big Sur.